# How to UPDATE using subquery that SELECT's column relative to the parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I can't seem to get around this MySQL limitation without changing the entire query or splitting it into a separate `SELECT`/`UPDATE` operation pair:

```
UPDATE `animal`
LEFT JOIN `animalFriends`
    ON (`animalFriends`.`animal_id_friend`=`animal`.`id`)
SET `animal`.`trainer_friend_name_latest`=
(
    SELECT `trainer`.`name`
    FROM `animalFitnessGroup`
    LEFT JOIN `trainer`
    ON (`animalFitnessGroup`.`trainer_id`=`trainer`.`id`)
    WHERE `animalFitnessGroup`.`animal_id_firstMember`=`animal`.`id` OR
   `animalFitnessGroup`.`animal_id_firstMember`=`animalFriends`.`animal_id_friend2`
    ORDER BY `animalFitnessGroup`.`id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
WHERE `animal`.`id`=123
```

This sort of query renders the error:

> You can't specify target table "animal" for update in FROM clause

While I'm sure there's a good reason for this, it's a bit frustrating since the query's intention is clear. Is there a simple workaround? Could `UPDATE FROM` be a solution... without rewriting this into subquery `SELECT` operations or two separate operations? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37284940/963901

Answer (score 0):

You can try joining all four tables together explicity in the outer `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE `animal`
LEFT JOIN `animalFriends`
    ON (`animalFriends`.`animal_id_friend`=`animal`.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `animalFitnessGroup`
    ON `animalFitnessGroup`.`animal_id_firstMember`=`animal`.`id` OR
       `animalFitnessGroup`.`animal_id_firstMember`=`animalFriends`.`animal_id_friend2`
LEFT JOIN `trainer`
    ON `animalFitnessGroup`.`trainer_id`=`trainer`.`id`
SET `animal`.`trainer_friend_name_latest` = `trainer`.`name`
WHERE `animal`.`id`=123
```

Without seeing data and having a deeper understanding of the query I cannot be certain that this will behave as you want.

Comment: There are many objects in the `animalFitnessGroup` table, and we're only trying to select the latest one. So, I'm not sure if a JOIN is going to work since it needs to be sorted?

Comment: Could you include sample data in your question?  It is difficult to visualize your query using only your attempt.

Comment: Well the issue is less the data and more that there's a limitation of `SELECT`-ing and `UPDATE`-ing the same table.

Comment: @BenGuild If you reveal some sample data and logic, there may be another strategy which avoids this situation.  This is why I asked for it.

Comment: That's always the case, I totally understand. But in this case I'm asking for help with a specific query... is essentially updating a column based on a subquery that references the table being updated.